# Vector of struct (copy_n and merge sort)

Tags: c++

I have a struct and vector of struct:

```
struct S
{
    int Efficiency;
    int Number;
};

std::vector<S> Empl;
```

I try to input Empl.Efficiency using copy_n:

```
std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), NumberOfEmpl, std::back_inserter(Empl.Efficiency));
```

But always appears error that vector doesn't contain Efficiency. How I can input Empl.Efficiency?

And also how I can sort by efficiency and save pair efficiency&number if I using merge sort?

```
void merge_sort(BidirIt first, BidirIt last, Compare cmp = Compare{})
{
    const auto n = std::distance(first, last);
    if (n > 1) {
        const auto middle = std::next(first, n / 2);
        merge_sort(first, middle, cmp);
        merge_sort(middle, last, cmp);
        std::inplace_merge(first, middle, last, cmp);
    }
}
...
merge_sort(std::begin(Empl.Efficiency), std::end(Epml.Efficiency));
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. `Efficiency` is an integer, not a vector.

Answer (score 1):

This can't work:

```
std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), NumberOfEmpl, std::back_inserter(Empl.Efficiency));
```

Because Empl is a vector, but Efficiency is a member of a struct inside that vector.  You can't "Broadcast" this way in C++.  However, you could do this:

```
std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), NumberOfEmpl, std::back_inserter(Empl));
```

If you implement:

```
std::ostream& operator >>(std::ostream& in, S& empl) {
    return in >> empl.Efficiency;
}
```

That is, you make an istream operator for your struct which reads into Efficiency and ignores Number.

Comment: I tried copy_n without efficiency, but there is the same error.  Also as for std::ostream operator: *a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token :ostream& operator*

Comment: @Kate: Please post your current code in the question now.